# Tidal locking and heat dissipation

Tags: astronomy, celestial-mechanics, tidal-effect

I need to know that how does one measure (approximate) the energy loss of a planet or satellite during the whole tidal locking process?
Where do I find this topic to study?

Comment: Have you read; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tidal_acceleration

Comment: Thank you. The link helped a lot.